# Access history report for MySQL - knowing who accessed the database and when

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if the is a way or tool that will enable me to have access history/report to my MySQL database (I have no root/shell access on the server). I would like to be able to know when and what user accessed the database, and which table, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mysql general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html) is used for this but you need access to the server and database to enable it. Be aware, even with connections logged like this, if requests are made from scripts on the server, I ain't sure this will give you the ip as the request is made from localhost.

Comment: Yup - looks like thats it. Thanks. However my hosring company warned me that this is a very I/O intensive procedure, any idea how much?

Comment: Every query made writes to file, and writing to a file is an expensive process. The more queries you have, the more you will bog down MySQL, this is not recommended on high traffic web sites but is more as a troubleshooting - debugging option. You can use it temporarily for a short while, but I recommend you make sure to have it disabled afterwards.